# Node js multiple routes get socket

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am using NodeJS, socket.io and express to create an application and I am wondering how can I determinate which socket (id/user) is on which router?
For example I have 10 users on my website, and I have 3 routes: /home, /about, /contact. How can I know which user is on which router?

Comment: Are you also using something (like socket.io-passport) to link the user in Express session with Socket.io? because that would a topic on its own

Comment: I am currently learning how all the "javascript on server" (node.js) works. I have a php background and I don't know so much about it. Yes I've heard about passport.js but I don't know yet how it is working. I need a registration/login functionality on my website but I don't know yet how I'm gonna do it and what's the "best" practice.

Comment: checkout updated answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly to know "which user" itself you'll need a system with sessions and cookies to identify a particular user each time they make a different request. [Passport.JS](http://passportjs.org/) makes this really easy.

Secondly to share this same user among Express route and Socket.io handler would require sharing the session information between the two. For Passport.js there's [socket.io-passport](https://github.com/jfromaniello/passport.socketio) that does this.

Lastly, when client-side Socket.io initiates a connection request to the server by `io.connect()` it sets the referrer header of the request to current URL, which can be accessed on server-side with `socket.request.headers.referer`

With all that in place you'll finally be able to tell which user is on which route:

```
app.get('/about', function(req, res, next){
    // req.user is on '/about' path
});
```

```
var URL = require('url');
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    var user = socket.request.user;
    var path = URL.parse(socket.request.headers.referer).path;
    // user is on -> path
});
```

Comment: I would have given you multiple upvotes but I only can one. :) Thanks for your updated answer! Please check out my other node.js questions :)